# Derivatives of a polynomials on a Banach space as a multilinear maps

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, tensor-products, rough-path-theory

I'm reading "Differential Equations Driven by Rough Paths" by Lyon, Caruana and Lévy and I can't wrap my head around the following part (beginning of Section 1.4.2).

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional Banach space. For an integer $K \geq 0$ let $P: V \to \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial of degree $k$. Let $X : [0,T] \to V$ be a Lipschitz continuous path. Then, if $P^1:V \to L(V,\mathbb{R})$ denotes the derivative of $P$, then Taylor's theorem asserts that, for all $t \in [0,T]$,
$$
P(X_t) = P(X_0) + \int_0^t P^1(X_s)dX_s.
$$
Let now $P^2 : V \to L(V \otimes V, R)$ denote the second derivative of $P$. Recall
that $L(V \otimes V, R)$ is the space of bilinear forms on $V$ . Then, by substitution
into the last expression, we get
$$
P(X_t) = P(X_0) + P^1(X_0) \int_{0<u_1<t}dX_{u_1} + \iint_{0<u_1<u_2<t} P^2(X_u) dX_{u_1} \otimes dX_{u_2}.
$$
Integrals are understood in Young's sense.

I have trouble understanding the following concepts:

1. I'm only familiar with polynomials over rings, not Banach spaces. Where does the multiplication come from?
2. Why is the derivative of a polynomial a map from $V$ to the space of linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$? I'm completely lost here.
3. How do we obtain the first Taylor representation?
4. I guess that the formulation of the second derivative as a bilinear map follows from the same reasoning as for the first derivative, but nonetheless. What is the intuition?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Ask one question at a time. Each one of these questions require substantial background. But in a nutshell, it all boils down to calculus in normed spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **homogenous polynomial** of degree $r$ in a vector space is the composition of a $r$-linear function $N$ (with values in some vector space) and the $r$-diagonal map $v \mapsto v^{(r)} = (v, \ldots, v) \in V^r.$ Thus, a homogeneous polynomial of degree $r$ is $f_r(v) = N(v^{(r)}).$ A **polynomial** of degree at most $n \in \mathbf{N},$ is the sum up to $r \leq n$ of homogenous polynomials of degree $r.$ Polynomials in vector spaces in general do not have product defined. However, there is the following construction, suppose $W_1, W_2$ are two vector spaces and $P:W_1 \times W_2 \to X$ a "product" (i.e., bilinear map, $X$ being another vector space). Suppose $f_s$ and $g_t$ are homogenous polynomials of degree $s$ and $t$ with values in $W_1$ and $W_2,$ respectively. The product of $f_s$ and $g_t$ relative to $P$ is $P \circ (f_s, g_t).$ This is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $s+t.$ To see this, consider $s$-linear and $t$-linear functions $M$ and $N$ such that $f_s(v) = M(v^{(s)})$ and $g_t(v) = N(v^{(t)}).$ Then $(P \circ (f_s, g_t))(v) = P\circ(M(v^{(s)}), N(v^{(t)}))$ and it is easy to see that $(v_1, \ldots, v_s, v_{s+1}, \ldots, v_{s+t}) \mapsto P(M(v_1, \ldots, v_s), N(v_{s+1},\ldots,v_{s+t}))$ is $(s+t)$-linear. If now $f = \sum_{s \leq m} f_s$ and $g = \sum_{t \leq n}$ are two polynomials (not necessarily homogenous), then their product is $P \circ (f,g),$ and by bilinearity of $P,$ we can write this as $\sum_{s \leq m,t \leq n} P \circ (f_s, g_t),$ which is a sum of homogenous polynomials of degree $s+t,$ and therefore the product of $f$ and $g$ relative to $P$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m+n.$ The authors are using $P:\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ the usual product of numbers $P(a,b) = ab.$

I hope the previous answered your *first* question; all other questions should receive their own thread.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wasn't sure how deep the constructions were, so I thought all those questions could be answered at once.

Comment: @Bombadil The derivate in normed spaces is a function from the original space to the space of linear functions (with domain and codomain those vector spaces underlying the original function); this is true for any differentiable function, not just the polynomials. The first Taylor representation follows from the FTC which is valid in Banach spaces, and the second derivative is the derivative of the derivative (which is linear and linear, hence bilinear). That's the gist of it.

Comment: Thank you, this clears the other questions I had quite a bit.